# How to move a bare root plant from one place to another?

Tags: flowers, transplanting, roots, outdoor

There is a small plant at my office garden, about 15 cm tall (6 inches), and it has a flower.

I live at about **40 min away from my work place**. I want to take it home, where I will plant it in a small pot. It's not an indoor plant.

**How do I transfer this**?  I'm planning to take it in my water bottle soaking the roots in water.

Comment: Why not put it in a small plastic container with some soil, just for the trip home?

Comment: i'm afraid it shouldn't die! I won't be able to find a container like thing around the place. Is the bottle thing a bad idea mate? Thanks

Comment: If you are afraid that the plant dies, the bottle seems not like the best idea. A plastic plant pot costs maybe a few euros (dollars). Just fill it with some garden soil for transport, and at home transfer it to your final pot, with potting soil.

Comment: A photograph of the plant in question would be helpful - its hard to judge how big the rootball might be without knowing what the plant is. Its likely a plant,even at that size, may have a rootball too large to fit in something as small as a bottle. Can you add a  photo?

Comment: If you really can't buy a plastic container, try to put the plant with some soil in a plastic bag... It will survive for 40 minutes.

Comment: I actually brought a small pot today.. I'll put e'm in before i go home and take the baby home with me haha. Thanks guys cheers.

Comment: Do you need to hide it while "transferring it out of the office" to your home? Is there a security guy at the entrance? Do you know the location of cameras? Alarm systems?

Comment: @VividD hahah yeah i did it like mission Impossible, updates on the plants shes  <3

Answer (score 1):

Take the plant together with some soil around its roots and place it in a plastic cup or cut the lower part of a plastic bottle and use it as a cup. If neither is available, wrap a wet paper napkin around roots and soil, then place it in a plastic bag.

If the roots come out without any soil, place them in water, using any kind of container you have. If you don't have a container for water, follow the wet napkin method, but be careful to wrap it gently, otherwise the roots might be damaged. The plastic bag keeps moisture inside, prevents the napkin to come apart and protects roots from accidentally tearing them.

Keep the leaves outside the plastic bag if the weather is hot.